# GCP - How can I create an HL7v2 store configured with a Pub/Sub topic using curl?

Tags: google-iam, google-cloud-healthcare

In order to transmit HL7v2 messages over TCP/IP connections using the minimal lower layer protocol (MLLP) I'm following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare-api/docs/how-tos/mllp-adapter). When I get to the part where I create an HL7v2 store configured with a Pub/Sub topic ([here](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare-api/docs/how-tos/mllp-adapter#creating_an_hl7v2_store_configured_with_a_cloud_pubsub_topic)) I get an error.

This is what I typed in my terminal:

```sh
curl -X POST \
    --data "{
      'notificationConfigs': [
        {
          'pubsubTopic': 'projects/PROJECT_ID/topics/PUBSUB_TOPIC',
          'filter': ''
        }
      ]
    }" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
    "https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION/datasets/DATASET_ID/hl7V2Stores?hl7V2StoreId=HL7V2_STORE_ID"
```

This is the error I get:

```sh
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission healthcare.hl7V2Stores.create denied on resource projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION/datasets/DATASET_ID (or it may be malformed or not exist)",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

The Dataset `projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION/datasets/DATASET_ID` exists, I double checked it.
So, is this somehow related to my permissions (IAM policy) ? I don't understand because I am `Administer HL7v2 Stores`.

How can I create my Datastore without getting this error ?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the command `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` was not returning the correct token but `gcloud auth print-access-token` is.

So with the right auth token, the command works and I get the correct response:

```sh
{
  "name": "projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION/datasets/DATASET_ID/hl7V2Stores/HL7V2_STORE_ID",
  "notificationConfigs": [
    {
      "pubsubTopic": "projects/PROJECT_ID/topics/PUBSUB_TOPIC"
    }
  ]
}
```